# Grails - Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment is forbidden ERROR

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails

Environment

```
Grails 2.4.4
PostgreSQL 9.4
JDK 1.7
```

I'm trying to get `Grails Database Reverse Engineer Plugin` to work. I went through some errors and now I'm stuck with these errors. 
I'm a newbie and not quite familiar with hibernate. What can I do to remedy these errors? I tried to add `hibernate.properties` file but that didn't work. (I'm not sure I even did it right...)

```
/Grails_Workspace/dbTest/target/work/plugins/db-reverse-engineer-4.0.0/src/groovy/grails/plugin/reveng/Reenigne.groovy: 92: Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment#DRIVER is forbidden @ line 92, column 14.
        properties[Environment.DRIVER] = driverClass
.               ^
.    
Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment#PASS is forbidden @ line 93, column 14.
        properties[Environment.PASS] = password
.               ^
.    
Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment#URL is forbidden @ line 94, column 14.
        properties[Environment.URL] = url
.               ^
.    
Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment#USER is forbidden @ line 95, column 14.
        properties[Environment.USER] = username
.               ^
.    
Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment#DIALECT is forbidden @ line 97, column 15.
            properties[Environment.DIALECT] = dialect
.                ^
.    
Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment#DEFAULT_SCHEMA is forbidden @ line 100, column 15.
            properties[Environment.DEFAULT_SCHEMA] = defaultSchema
.                ^
.    
Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment#DEFAULT_CATALOG is forbidden @ line 103, column 15.
            properties[Environment.DEFAULT_CATALOG] = defaultCatalog
                 ^
```

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

Plugin Block

```
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"
    compile ":postgresql-extensions:4.6.1"
    compile ":joda-time:1.5"
    compile ":db-reverse-engineer:4.0.0"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
    //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `plugins` block from your `BuildConfig.groovy`?

Comment: @Burt Beckwith, I've edited my post. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what's up, that works fine for me with a similarly configured test app. Since the reverse-engineer plugin is only used infrequently to generate domain classes but it's not used at all at compile or runtime, you should be able to create a separate app just for use with the plugin. Remove everything you can from the `plugins` and `dependencies` block that's not used or might cause a problem (i.e. everything but `hibernate4` and `db-reverse-engineer`, plus `postgresql-extensions` _only_ if it's needed) and do the work there, then move the domain classes to the real app

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. I created a testApp to just get the domain class running. I'll  do it again with just bare minimum.

Comment: @Burt Beckwith, I've created a new app with no plugins but `hibernate4` and `dbReverseEngineer4`. I still get the same error. When I did `grails compile` with `hibernate4` plugin only, it compiled just fine. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: @Burt Beckwith, Thank you very much for your time and help. 
I finally got it to work. I was poking through the hibernate issues and ended up learning that I didn't have the `postgresql driver` under `dependencies` in `BuildConfig.groovy` file. It was such a simple mistake and took me a week to figure it out. But along the process, I got to learn a lot about Grails though. I appreciate everything you do for Groovy/Grails community.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I am having same problem. I have `database driver` under `dependencies` in `BuildConfig.groovy` file.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. I used 3.0.0

Use

```
compile ":db-reverse-engineer:3.0.0"
remove 
runtime ":db-reverse-engineer:4.0.0"
```